# Majority of Database Connections going to one Aurora DB

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-aurora

I have an AWS Mysql Aurora DB setup to autoscale when it reaches a certain CPU threshold, that said, looking at usage a majority of DB connections are only going to a single DB. Aurora is meant to load balance this, but is there anything additional I can do to ensure a more even distribution of DB connections? I'm having some latency issues with my website, and I think they could be originating from here as all other metrics are normal. [image]

Comment: you should ask this at server fault, which seems to be the better place for it